# How to Retrieve and Render Data from Firebase using ID/Key (with React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-router

I’m trying to access data from the Firebase server and then proceed to open a view page of the object. My routing is working for sure I think.

The index component I want the clicked post to link from is this:

```
renderPosts() {
  return _.map(this.state.posts, (post, key) => {
    return (
      <div key={key} className="thumbnail">
        <h2>
          <Link to="/view/posts/{post}">
            {post.title}
          </Link>
        </h2>
        <p>{post.body}</p>
      </div>
    );

  });
}
```

I tried to link to the post cause I figured it work based on the componentDidMount used to build that function. And I imported the view component into it as well.

The app.js page is as this:

```
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <div>
            <Nav/>
          </div>
          <Switch>

            <Route path='/' exact component={List}/>
            <Route path='/new' component={NewPost}/>
            <Route path='/view' component={View}/>


          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter> 
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

And the view.js page is as follows:

```
    componentWillMount(){

    let postRef = database().ref('posts').orderByKey().limitToLast(100);
    postRef.on('value', snapshot => {

      let post = { title: snapshot.title, id: snapshot.key };
      this.setState({ posts: [post].concat(this.state.posts) });
    });
    console.log(postRef);
  }

  }

  render() {


    return (
      <div >

      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Sorry. It’s a bit bare now cause I removed everything I have tried. I used a couple articles and videos to try to figure it out but nothing worked. The original lifecycle method and constructor I used for the index page however is this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      body: '',
      posts:{}
    };
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.onHandleSubmit = this.onHandleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
```

and

```
  componentDidMount(){
    database.on('value', snapshot => {
      this.setState({
        posts: snapshot.val()
      });

    });
  }
```

I’m sorry, I know it is a lot to get through but I thought I should cover everything that might be useful. But to sum up: My issues are how to retrieve the post from the database and then add the key that Firebase automatically makes to the link and thus render it in a new page.

Ps. My database is exported as this

```
export const database = firebase.database().ref('/posts’);
```

Comment: Any ideas here @LukeSchlangen? Sorry to put you out again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the question but it sounds like the `post` key contains the value you want for the link. If that's the case then try...

```
renderPosts(){
    return Object.keys(this.state.posts).map((post, index)=>(
        <div key={index} className="thumbnail">
        <h2>
          <Link to={`/view/posts/${post}`}>
            {this.state.posts[post].title}
          </Link>
        </h2>
        <p>{this.state.posts[post].body}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    );
```

then you should just be able to call your renderPosts function in your render method.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div >
       {renderPosts()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

It might take a little while to get the post data if you're calling firebase so only call the render method when the post data shows up.

```
render() {
        return (
          <div >
           {this.state.posts && renderPosts()}
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Comment: If I have completely misunderstood the question and the problem can you please rephrase what you are trying to do because it is hard to understand. What is the problem? Does it say anything in the console? Please share any errors you get.

Comment: thank you for your reply! I think this is going the right way! When I added your snippet the index page changed only to show all the unique ID’s from firebase so I know how to access it now. But still, I lost the index of posts and still not sure how to route them to be rendered. Can you please explain a bit more? 
thank you

Comment: There was a silly typo in the first code chunk in my response above. I forgot to add the map function. Try now.

Comment: Ahh! so thats how you do that. I figured it was something like that but wasn’t sure how to go around doing that. Thank you very much! It is back to normal and the ID appends to the link perfectly!! 
Now... to figure out how to render it on the view page. 
Thanks again!

Comment: Nice, the link works fine. And still goes to the view page. I take it it is a variation on the code you wrote in order to retrieve the id from the link and then render it yes? 
Hmm

Comment: I'm glad that helped. I'm sorry, I don't understand what the question is in the comment above. Are you asking me what I am doing inside the Link's to brackets? Please clarify.

Comment: Hi!
I’m asking how to then pass the selected post into the view component to render it. Sorry if I’m asking too much. You’ve helped a lot already. 

also the last bit code of you wrote. The third one, I try using it but get an error saying renderPosts isn’t defined when it’s literally right there. 
Not sure if what I’m trying to do depends on that or not. But to sum up, I want to then take the post clicked and then render it on a new page.

Comment: Write a new component for the page and create a route to it. The route path will be `path='/view/posts/:postId` since that's what you put in the link. Then you can use `this.props.match.params.postId` inside the new page to get the key. Fire a new call to firebase in componentDidMount if you need to get data specific to that page. This is a separate question though, you should open a new stack question so that people can help you with that separately. Have a look at the react router docs so that you ask you understand enough to ask a specific question.

Comment: Seperately, if the second code chunk is working then ignore the third one.

Comment: I don’t really get it but thanks. And yeah. I will make a new questions.
thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164549/discussion-between-al-m-and-josh-pittman).

Comment: Co-ordinating time differences is too much hassle, did my best to explain what I mean here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48617671/how-do-i-render-data-from-selected-object/48622245#48622245

Comment: Thank you. I replied to that. Can you please check if it’s not too troublesome?