# How do I render data from selected object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router

Currently trying to learn react with firebase and keep getting some minor roadblocks.

As of now, I am trying to render the data from a selected item in a new page. The index page contains the following:

```
renderPosts(){
    return Object.keys(this.state.posts).map((post, index)=>(
        <div key={index} className="thumbnail">
        <h2>
          <Link to={`/view/posts/${post}`}>
            {this.state.posts[post].title}
          </Link>
        </h2>
        <p>{this.state.posts[post].body}</p>
        </div>
      ));
}

render() {
   return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {this.renderPosts()}
        </div>
        <View/>
      </div>
   )
}
```

As you can see it appends the ID of that post into the link so what I want to do now is to reach back into firebase and render the corresponding  data of the item with that ID alone in a new page.

The ViewPost.js file as so:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      body: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    database.on('value', snapshot => {
      this.setState({
        post: snapshot.val()
      });
      this.props.match.params.postId;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
       {this.state.props.title}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Can you please show me what I’m doing wrong and how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a missing piece in your example, your router. First, you need to add a new route to the router.

```
 <Route path='/view/posts/:postId' component={ViewPost}/>
```

This is the route then you are telling the router you want to go to in the link tag in the render method you created:

```
<Link to={`/view/posts/${post}`}>
```

I am assuming the component you want to render when you go to that link is the code you wrote in ViewPost.js sample above. If you import this component as `ViewPost` in your router file it should work now.

Click on the link, and it will load up that component.

Next, inside the component, you want to call the data associated with the key you see in the URL. The grab the key value form the URL you use `this.props.match.params.postId`.

Now that you have access to the key value you can do a regular firebase call in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount(){
    database
     .ref(`posts/${this.props.match.params.postId}`) 
     .on('value', snap => {
          this.setState({post: snapshot.val()});
     })
}
```

I hope that made sense. First make a route, then get the value of the key from the URL, then use the key value to do a database request inside the component that you end up at.

Comment: Hello again,
Thanks so much for this. Yes I have the route set up like that in app.js. 

I’m still getting errors. I think I followed your instructions right too.

This is what I’ve got right now
https://jsfiddle.net/z18yzjo5/

Comment: First off, network requests take a little while so replace `{this.state.post.title }` with `{this.state.post && this.state.post.title}` in your viewPost function. Also set the default state value of post to null or undefined. That it will only show when it has something to show.

Comment: There is also a huge space between datbase and ref in the componentDidMount method on your fiddle. Make sure that isn't in your actual code.

Comment: the errors are always posts or post not defined and type null

and since adding your code i now get [Error] TypeError: Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__firebase__["a" /* database */]) is not a function etc.

then there is
Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

Please check the code for the List component.

Comment: what is the list component? You imported it into the fiddle and then never used it. Comment . out the import while we are debugging.

Comment: yeah, the only error now is TypeError: Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__firebase__["a" /* database */]) is not a function. (In 'Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__firebase__["a" /* database */])()', 'Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__firebase__["a" /* database */])' is an instance of Reference)

Comment: the list component is the index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164559/discussion-between-al-m-and-josh-pittman).

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but i don’t know what happened, the error came back

Comment: It was literally the same error as before about the this.match.params. It's weird it was working perfectly then when you left the error came back and I have no clue why. I even put back the view function and tried to backtrack but it still didn't work.

Comment: I would keep the view function out since its just clutter. Just render what you need in render instead of rendering functions for now. Cycle back through the debug process we went through. Comment out the componentDidMount in view and then console log this.props.match.params.postId and see if anything shows up in your console.

Comment: I did that already. Didn’t work. still says undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.match.params')

Comment: Update, the console.log is working now once i removed the componentDidMount, but also gave a security 18 DOM-something error, but that’s gone now too.

Comment: Wait, it’s working again. I am so confused. I didn’t change anything. Just commented out and returned it and it’s working again.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's working for you now.